# Tell which interface(wifi or wire) is used(active) in OSX programmatically

Tags: macos, network-interface

SCNetworkReachability can't tell whether it's connected via wire or wifi. Another possible way to do this is getting the name of the active interface, and then compare with those names getting from SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName, and then using SCNetworkInterfaceGetInterfaceType to get the type. The problem with this one is that SCNetworkInterface* seems doesn't work for VPN connection.

```
std::string bsdName = get_primary_bsdName();
if (bsdName.length() == 0)
    return NotDetected;

CFArrayRef interfaces;
CFIndex num_interfaces;
CFIndex i;
SCNetworkInterfaceRef interface;
CFStringRef name_CFString;
CFStringRef bsdname_CFString;
CFStringRef friendly_name_CFString;
CFStringRef interface_type_CFString;

interfaces = SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll();
if (interfaces == NULL) {
    return NotDetected;
}

name_CFString = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault,
    bsdName.c_str(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
if (name_CFString == NULL) {
    CFRelease(interfaces);
    return NotDetected;
}
eNetworkStatus retVal = NotDetected;

num_interfaces = CFArrayGetCount(interfaces);
for (i = 0; i < num_interfaces; i++) {
    interface = (SCNetworkInterfaceRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interfaces, i);
    CFShow(interface);
    bsdname_CFString = SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName(interface);
    if (bsdname_CFString == NULL) {
        continue;
    }
    if (CFStringCompare(name_CFString, bsdname_CFString, 0) == 0)
    {
        interface_type_CFString = SCNetworkInterfaceGetInterfaceType(interface);
        if (CFStringCompare(interface_type_CFString,
            kSCNetworkInterfaceTypeIEEE80211, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
            retVal = ReachableViaWiFi;
        else if (CFStringCompare(interface_type_CFString,
            kSCNetworkInterfaceTypeBluetooth, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
            retVal = ReachableViaBlueTooth;
        else if (CFStringCompare(interface_type_CFString,
            kSCNetworkInterfaceTypeModem, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
            retVal = ReachableViaModem;
        else if (CFStringCompare(interface_type_CFString,
            kSCNetworkInterfaceTypePPP, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
            retVal = ReachableViaPPP;
        else if (CFStringCompare(interface_type_CFString,
            kSCNetworkInterfaceTypeWWAN, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
            retVal = ReachableViaWWAN;
        else
            retVal = ReachableViaWIRE;
    }
}

CFRelease(interfaces);
CFRelease(name_CFString);
```